# inconsistent ticks and element placement with fig.savefig and jupyter notebook display

Tags: matplotlib

I have some matplotlib code to produce plots.

Displaying this figure in jupyter notebook I get the following result:

[image: plot rendered by jupyter notebook]

Which differs throughly from what I get when using `fig.savefig:

[image: plot saved thorugh savefig in png format]

As you can see, the position of the title and the subplots yticks appear inconsistent. I'm not bothered by the different background colour behaviour, which is due to the first pic being screenshotted.

I want to save this figure in the exact same fashion as it is displayed in the jupyter notebook.

To my understanding this is due to the different backends used when saving a figure or displaying it.
I've tried a few thing to achieve this result but with no success so far, namely:

- using dpi keyword for `fig.savefig`
- using `bbox_inches='tight'` keyword for `fig.savefig`

Comment: Pretty hard to tell without knowing what code you are calling.  Sometimes there can be hysteresis between bbox_inches=tight and constrained_layout or tight_layout.  I’d turn off bbox_inches=tight in Jupyter.

Comment: @JodyKlymak thank you. I have not posted the code because it's a contrived. figures are created and modified between a function inside a module and the notebook itself. figures are created with `tight_layout` keyword set to True and some figsize specified. turning off bbox_inches isn't helping :(

Comment: The in-line backend for Jupyter also uses bbox_inches=tight.

Comment: You also have a lot of code that is being placed in a bespoke manner - I assume "count range" and the title are being placed manually.  You might prefer to look at using `set_title("boo", loc='left')` and `fig.supylabel()`, and use constrained_layout instead of tight_layout.

Comment: @JodyKlymak thank you but both the "count range" and the title are placed using `fig.supylabel()` and `fig.suptitle()`

Comment: So, which positioning parameters do you use in `fig.supylabel()` and `fig.suptitle()`?

Comment: neither of those are compatible with tight_layout, so I'm surprised it works at all.  For debugging, you may wish to remove the legend as well, and you should tell us if it is a figure legend or an axes legend.

Comment: @JohanC positioning is dealt with through `fig.suptitle('...', x = 0.34)`. I'm using no positioning keywords for `fig.supylabel()`. the legend position is determined by `bbox_to_anchor` keyword.

Comment: @deppep its confusing what more help you need at this point.  You've  still not stated if you are using the inline backend of not in jupyter.  If you are, that explains the different placement of the elements.